# How to come up with the "object interface", instead of "data type" in python?

Tags: python

Here is one of the multitude of the citations, regarding the importance of the attention to "object interface" in definition of the functions in python, instead of taking into account the data type for the arguments:

> "in Python, this concept does not really apply; polymorphism in Python
>   is based on object interfaces, not types." (Learning Python, 4th
>   Edition by Lutz)

Now, I need to confess that I can't realize above argument, deservedly...!
Just consider below example, is which in C++, as a function to model the connection of two artificial neurons:

```c++
void Neuron::connectTo(Neuron successor, Neuron predecessor, const int& weight)   
{
    successor.setInput(1, predecessor.getId());
    predecessor.setOutput(1, successor.getId());
    Connection c;
    c.setWeight(weight, predecessor.getId(), successor.getId());
}
```

Obviously, both the arguments' types and the output one do matter, in view of the credibility of the inputs.

Does any body guide me to transfer from "data type" idea to the "object interface" paradigm, corresponding to this example?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for, since your C++ example uses a concrete class rather than an interface.

Comment: Basically, in Python, your `Neuron` shouldn't care what *type* the `successor` and `predecessor` arguments are, as long as both objects sensibly implement `setInput` and `getId`. This is often referred to as "duck typing".

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't have a formal definition of an interface, rather it relies on ["duck typing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) - if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it has a duck interface.

The usual idiom is to use the methods on the object that you expect to exist. If they fail, then the object didn't provide the proper interface. You can catch an exception at that point or just ignore it and let the trace dump indicate the problem.

Comment: That doesn't sound functional!... Just imagine a big program with thousands of lines... Lack of type(in the manner, you just explained) might lead to a vast pool of exceptions!!! How could one handle that?!

Comment: @matinking that's one big argument people use for having a type system. The usual answer is to use unit tests to make sure things work the way you expect them to.